# How to constrain package versions in conda?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I'm working in a conda environment with a bunch of packages preinstalled (conda list has 360 packages, a lot of ML tools and some bioconda).  I sometimes need to add a package; however, I find that `conda install newpackage` is often extremely slow (hours or days spent at "Solving environment"), and if it ever finishes, it often suggests updates to packages I really don't want to touch.

I'd like to pin the current versions of some of the core packages (python, numpy, scipy, etc) so that modifying them isn't even considered possible by conda.  This is both for speed, and to avoid any unintentional updates.  If that means a certain package I want to try adding can't be installed, that's okay!  I'd much rather have a quick answer like "newpackage conflicts with your version of numpy" than no answer.  I can then decide if I want to ignore the conflict; make a simple environment just for this one package; conda build locally, or whatever.

How do I do that?

See also: https://www.anaconda.com/blog/understanding-and-improving-condas-performance (which didn't solve the problem)

Comment: `conda install newpackage is often extremely slow (hours or days spent at "Solving environment"), and if it ever finishes, it often suggests updates to packages I really don't want to touch.`  - have you tried [mamba](https://github.com/TheSnakePit/mamba)? It's a drop-in replacement for conda and it's really, really fast.

Comment: Are you using a single environment for all your projects? For the best performance and stability, try building the env from an environment.yml file.

Comment: @AMC I'm using Amazon AMIs which come with an environment; a lot of the packages seem to be custom builds (and not completely sure where those come from).  I can of course always get a fresh copy by creating a new instance from the AMI, but not necessarily create an env from environment.yml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Package Pinning

Packages can be pinned to specific versions on a per-environment basis. See [the documentation on package pinning](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#preventing-packages-from-updating-pinning). For example, suppose we want to pin `numpy` and `scipy` to the exact versions we currently have in an env called `foo`. We could process the output of `conda list` to match the expected syntax of the Conda pinning specification:

```bash
conda activate foo
conda list "^(numpy|scipy)$" | tail -n+4 | awk '{ print $1 " ==" $2 }' > $CONDA_PREFIX/conda-meta/pinned
```

A few things to note here:

- `conda list` takes a regex: use that to your advantage
- `tail` is just to skip the header
- this depends on being in the activated env to define `$CONDA_PREFIX`
- this overwrites any existing `pinned` file

## Freeze Installed

A less labor intensive means of keeping everything constant is to use the `--freeze-installed` flag. However, in more recent versions of Conda this is used by default in the first round of solving. So really all this flag does now is to skip the second round of solving that allows for packages that are not part of the explicit specifications to be updated.

## PyPI Packages

PyPI packages installed by Pip require some additional configuration to get Conda to pin them. Specifically, one needs the following syntax in the `envs/<env>/conda-meta/pinned` file:

```
numpy=1.21.4=pypi*
```

That is, indicate that `pypi` should be in the build string. And for this to be respected, one must enable Pip interoperability and allow for flexible channel prioritization:

```
## settings only for this environment
conda activate foo
conda config --env --set pip_interop_enabled True
conda config --env --set channel_priority flexible
```

Enabling this tells Conda to regard PyPI packages as valid substitutes for solving dependencies.

Personally, I would be careful using this since Conda is a general package manager and sometimes packages installed via Pip (such as `yaml` or `wget`) do not correspond to the Conda package by the same name. Hence, why I use `--env` in the example to only enable this configuration setting *within* that **foo** environment.