# How do I Prevent Anaconda 'conda update --all' from Downgrading my Tensorflow installation

Tags: anaconda, conda, tensorflow2.0

I have installed Tensorflow 2.2.0 in an Anaconda virtual environment.  If I try to upgrade the packages in my environment with 'conda update --all' it tries to revert my tensorflow to '1.14.0' from the conda-forge channel.

I installed tensorflow 2.2.0:

```
$ conda install tensorflow==2.2.0
```

There's no channel showing up in conda's list, so I setting a channel priority probably wouldn't help.

```
$ conda list tensorflow
# packages in environment at /home/ubuntu/anaconda2/envs/ai:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
tensorflow                2.2.0           mkl_py36h5a57954_0  
tensorflow-base           2.2.0           mkl_py36hd506778_0  
tensorflow-datasets       1.2.0                    py36_0    anaconda
tensorflow-estimator      2.2.0              pyh95af2a2_0    conda-forge
tensorflow-metadata       0.14.0             pyhe6710b0_1  


$ conda update --all
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): - NVIDIA: no NVIDIA devices found
done
Solving environment: | 
Warning: 2 possible package resolutions (only showing differing packages):
  - anaconda/linux-64::tensorflow-datasets-1.2.0-py36_0
  - defaults/linux-64::tensorflow-datasets-1.2.0-py36done


==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 4.8.4
  latest version: 4.9.1

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda



## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /home/ubuntu/anaconda2/envs/ai


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    awscli-1.18.169            |   py36h5fab9bb_0         1.8 MB  conda-forge
    boto3-1.16.9               |     pyhd8ed1ab_0          70 KB  conda-forge
    botocore-1.19.9            |     pyhd3deb0d_0         4.1 MB  conda-forge
    hypothesis-5.41.0          |     pyhd8ed1ab_0         222 KB  conda-forge
    tornado-6.1                |   py36h1d69622_0         644 KB  conda-forge
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:         6.8 MB

The following packages will be REMOVED:

  _tflow_select-2.3.0-mkl
  aiohttp-3.7.2-py36h8c4c3a4_0
  astunparse-1.6.3-py_0
  async-timeout-3.0.1-py_1000
  blinker-1.4-py_1
  cachetools-4.1.1-py_0
  google-auth-1.23.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  google-auth-oauthlib-0.4.1-py_2
  idna_ssl-1.1.0-py36h9f0ad1d_1001
  multidict-4.7.5-py36h8c4c3a4_2
  oauthlib-3.0.1-py_0
  opt_einsum-3.3.0-py_0
  pyjwt-1.7.1-py_0
  requests-oauthlib-1.3.0-pyh9f0ad1d_0
  tensorboard-plugin-wit-1.7.0-pyh9f0ad1d_0
  typing-extensions-3.7.4.3-0
  yarl-1.6.2-py36h8c4c3a4_0

The following packages will be UPDATED:

  awscli                            1.18.168-py36h5fab9bb_0 --> 1.18.169-py36h5fab9bb_0
  boto3                                 1.16.8-pyhd8ed1ab_0 --> 1.16.9-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  botocore                              1.19.8-pyhd3deb0d_0 --> 1.19.9-pyhd3deb0d_0
  gast                                           0.3.3-py_0 --> 0.4.0-pyh9f0ad1d_0
  hypothesis                            5.40.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0 --> 5.41.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  tornado                              6.0.4-py36h8c4c3a4_2 --> 6.1-py36h1d69622_0

The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:

  tensorboard        conda-forge/noarch::tensorboard-2.3.0~ --> conda-forge/linux-64::tensorboard-1.14.0-py36_0
  tensorflow         pkgs/main::tensorflow-2.2.0-mkl_py36h~ --> conda-forge::tensorflow-1.14.0-hc3e5e64_0
  tensorflow-base    pkgs/main::tensorflow-base-2.2.0-mkl_~ --> conda-forge::tensorflow-base-1.14.0-py36hc3e5e64_0
  tensorflow-estima~ conda-forge/noarch::tensorflow-estima~ --> conda-forge/linux-64::tensorflow-estimator-1.14.0-py36h5ca1d4c_0


Proceed ([y]/n)? n


CondaSystemExit:
```

Comment: What does your conda configuration look like, specifically the `.condarc` file? It looks like the solver is being told that `conda-forge` should be treated as higher priority than the main Anaconda channel.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to constrain package versions in conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62747419/how-to-constrain-package-versions-in-conda)