# How to modify .condarc file or use pinning to force conda to install the noarch selenium version when running "conda update --all"?

Tags: python, selenium, anaconda, conda

I would like to install selenium v4.1.0 on Anaconda python on Windows.

https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/selenium

If you run `conda install selenium`, conda will install selenium v3.11 if you're on Windows.

I ran `conda install selenium --channel conda-forge/noarch` to make conda install selenium v4.1.0 which is the noarch version.

The problem is when I run `conda update --all`, conda will downgrade my selenium back to v3.

After some googling, I discover modifying the config file .condarc may fix this problem. Question is how to modify .condarc to force conda to install the noarch selenium version when running "conda update --all"?

I am open to other solutions like pinning that will prevent conda from downgrading selenium back to v3 when I run `conda update --all`

I'm using python 3.9.12, conda 4.12.0

Comment: What version of Python and Conda are you using?  `python -V` and `conda -V`

Comment: @James I'm using python 3.9.12, conda 4.12.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @merv mentioned pin your package, which is a little unclear in the linked post. Open the `anaconda3` directory, go into `conda-meta` subfolder and create a file called `pinned`. Inside the file add 1 line: `selenium>=4.1.0` and test again. If you have an environment setup go into `anaconda3\envs` and inside the correct environment folder, go into the `conda-meta` folder there and save your `pinned` file.  I tested it and it would keep the `selenium>=4.1.0` using this method after doing a `conda update --all`

If you open Anaconda Prompt and type: `where python` it will usually show your installation directory, in case you don't know where it installed to.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I have verified that it works!
I've marked your answer as the correct one and more than happy to give you the bounty points that you so deserve :)

Answer (score 2):

Conda has a sufficiently expressive specification grammar (called [MatchSpec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57734390/570918)) to handle this - no need to mess around with `.condarc`.

```bash
conda install "conda-forge::selenium[version='>=4.1']"
```

It is possible that there are conflicts with the current environment, in which case, consider creating a new environment with Python 3.7 or later.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I have tested that after running `conda install "conda-forge::selenium[version='>=4.1']"`, selenium will still be upgraded back to v3 if I run `conda --update all`.

Comment: @user3848207 then use pinning (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62748267/570918)

Comment: As @merv mentioned pin your package.  Open the `anaconda3` directory, go into `conda-meta` and create a file called `pinned.`  Inside the file put in 1 line: `selenium>=4.1` and test again.  If you have an environment setup go into `envs` and inside the correct one, go into the `conda-meta` folder there and save your `pinned` file.